# How can I optimize this for loop in python when i append new elements to a list?

Tags: python, optimization

When I using an API  to get some json responses, I want to append the new needed data to an empty list with a for loop. How can I improve the running speed of this for loop?

```
for i in range(1,10):
    #parameter type of requests.get() must be str
    indicator = str(i) 
    #get response
    response = requests.get("URL"+indicator+"/f",
      headers={
        id
      }
    )
    python_ob = json.loads(response.text)
    team.append(python_ob['api']['teams'][0]['fullName'])
    team_id.append( python_ob['api']['teams'][0]['teamId'])
```

Comment: The greatest performance hit in this loop is most probably the HTTP request.

Comment: Which you can speed up slightly by using [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **list comprehension**. Its pretty fast. And you can use **%timeit** to test the speed of any function.

e.g.

```
x = []
def test():
   for i in range(1,10000):
       x.append(i)

%timeit test()
100000 loops, best of 3: 938 µs per loop
```

It took **938 µs** on an average

```
%timeit [i for i in range(1,10000)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop
```

It took **293 µs** on an average.

```
responses = []
for i in range(1,10000):
    #parameter type of requests.get() must be str
    indicator = str(i) 
    #get response
    response = requests.get("URL"+indicator+"/f",
      headers={
        id
      }
    )
    responses.append(json.loads(response))

 python_ob = json.loads(response.text)
 teams = [python_ob['api']['teams'][0]['fullName'] for python_ob in responses]
```

Comment: `%timeit` is new for me. Thanks,,

Comment: why do you think using list comprehension is faster?

Comment: Thank you! I will try it now.